# Series Expansion of $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{x}{1-x}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have come across an interesting result,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{x}{1-x}\right)
\quad\text{for}\ 
|x| \leq 1
$$

since,

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)
\quad\text{for}\ 
|x| \leq 1\\
\frac{x}{1-x} = x + x^2 + x^3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)
\quad\text{for}\ 
|x| \leq 1\\
$$
so in the limit to $\infty$, neglecting the 1,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right)
$$

Is the correct way to explain this as: the rate at which the functions increase with $x$ is the same save a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a way, but you should use the power series (which converge only for $\lvert x\rvert<1$). However, writing the second rational function in canonical form is simpler:
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=-1+\frac1{1-x},$$
hence the derivatives are equal.